# How to obtain multiple partial strings from a dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, string, dataframe

I am trying to obtain multiple partial strings from my dataframe and put those partial strings as added columns to my dataframe. Below you will find a simple data sample:

df

```
    Serienummer
15  SAA VKS MSI A1 R 7,500 1
29  SAA VKS MSI A1P 7,500 1
36  SAA VKS MSI A1 R 14,370 5
```

I want to obtain the following dataframe:

```
    Serienummer                  column1    column2  column3
15  SAA VKS MSI A1 R 7,500 1     A1         7,500    1
29  SAA VKS MSI A2P 7,500 1      A2         7,500    1
36  SAA VKS MSI A1 R 14,370 5    A1         14,370   5
```

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: What is the language? R? Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`pd.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) (to extract regex pattern groups) and `pd.concat`:

```
new_df = (pd.concat([df, df['Serienummer'].str
                    .extract(r'(\b[A-Z]\d+)[\sA-Z]+(\d+,\d+) (\d+)', expand=True)], 
                    axis=1))
```

---

```
                 Serienummer   0       1  2
0   SAA VKS MSI A1 R 7,500 1  A1   7,500  1
1    SAA VKS MSI A1P 7,500 1  A1   7,500  1
2  SAA VKS MSI A1 R 14,370 5  A1  14,370  5
```